# AngularJS setting the same ngapp more than once

Tags: angularjs

The problem I am having is I need the root element as an anchor tag, then need a div under the anchor tag. They will both be using the same angular controller which belongs to the same app. The databind on vm.Open works find inside the anchor tag, but it is not working inside the div tag. How can I have the div tag also bootstrap as 'app' with the controller 'ordercontrol'?
 Right now I have :

**My HTML**

```
<a data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ordercontrol as vm" href="#" data-ng-click="vm.Open = !vm.Open">{{vm.Open}}</a>

<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ordercontrol as vm" id="QuickOrderDiv">
    <div class="row">
        {{vm.Open}} //showing as '{{vm.Open}}' inside page
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to have a single app and two controller instances?

Answer (score 2):

[Per AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp), only one application can be bootstrapped per HTML document. There is probably not a good reason for you to try and declare and use multiple apps in one document. Depending on your intention, there are a few ways to proceed.

First, remember: assigning a [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) to an element (using the `ng-controller` directive) creates a new [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) that inherits from the parent. All elements, directives, and additional controllers used within that scope can use that controller to share functionality. So in essence, a controller is used to centralize models and application logic that is specific to an application and usually to a view (think of any functional task in your application, such as an order form or log in page; those are serviced by controllers).

If you want to reuse a *behavior* multiple times throughout your application, and that behavior is not specific to a particular view in your application (think of a component, like a date picker, or perhaps a shopping cart status icon/link) you may wish to encapsulate your logic in a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Now, there is some overlap (for example, directives *can* have a scope or controller of their own), and it may be confusing when to use one or the other. As I mentioned above, controllers are primarily intended to contain business logic for a view in your application. Directives are more orthogonal, encapsulated templates and logic that a) you can easily reuse across the views in your application, and b) extend existing HTML elements with richer mark-up and programmed behaviors. You can use a service (which is a single-instance object) to coordinate data between controllers and directives.

Another common issue new developers struggle with is maintaining or inheriting different states independently, considering that you can only have one `ng-view` element per document. In that case, consider [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

My wild guess for your case, you may want some sort of QuickOrder directive that binds to a value on `OrderController` to determine whether or not it should display, and contains additional template mark-up for displaying the order or whatever and the logic to manage it.